# Is "$x$ is an integer, $1 < x < 3$, and $x^2 = 4$" a proposition?

Tags: logic, terminology, propositional-calculus

A proposition is frequently defined as a statement that has one and only one truth value.

By themselves, "$x$ is an integer," "$1 < x < 3$," and "$x^2 = 4$" are not propositions because they may be true or false depending on the value of $x.$

Can someone explain why the conjunction of these three is considered a proposition?

Many thanks!

Comment: What source are you reading from that says this is a proposition? I'd think that it isn't.

Comment: A supplemental text written by a university professor several years ago. It's entirely possible that it is a misprint, but I have no way of verifying it with the author.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing that *may be* considered a proposition is the slightly different combination

> **If** $x$ is an integer **and** $1<x<3$, **then** $x^2=4$.

Formally, at least if we interpret "if--then" as denoting *material implication*, this is still a claim with a free variable, and therefore would not count as a "proposition" under the definition you quote -- no matter that its truth value *happens to* be "true" no matter what you plug in for $x$.

On the other hand, in informal mathematical speech, "if--then" not only encodes material implication but *also* tends to give you a universal quantification for free. (But it's up to the reader/listener to figure out which variables are quantified if there are more than one that appears in both the assumption and the conclusion). In this way, the above sentence can be used as an abbreviated form of

> **For every** $x$, if $x$ is an integer and $1<x<3$, then $x^2=4$.

This has no free variables and would therefore satisfy your definition of "proposition".

Comment: I like you're distinction between free variable and no free variable.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it isn't a proposition, merely a compound, non-conditional statement. Just as the truth of the three component statements depends on the identity of $x,$ the truth of the compound statement does, as well. In particular, it is true precisely when $x=2,$ but just the name $x$ is the only information we have, outside of that given in the statement, so there's no reason to suspect that $x=2,$ but it certainly could be true. Hence, the statement has undetermined truth-value, devoid of other context.

There are a few ways we could fix it. One would be to add context, such as:

> Suppose $x=2.$ The following are true:
>
> - $x$ is an integer.
> - $1<x<3.$
> - $x^2=4.$

Another is to combine the three component statements into a conditional, such as:

> If $x$ is an integer and $1<x<3,$ then $x^2=4.$

There may be other ways to "fix" it, but the upshot is that it needs "fixing" to be a proposition.

Comment: I didn't downvote (I did but then just un-downvoted after your edit).  It logic, particularly propositional logic, If P and Q are propositions, so is $P\land Q, P\to Q, P\lor Q$, etc.  That is, a propositional is not defined as "a conditional" or "an implication".  The main problem in this question is that it is a compound of predicate statements with a free variable, x.

Comment: As a side question, I wonder if there is some (possibly subtle) difference between a proposition and a propositional. Still, you're right: I was overgeneralizing. I have adjusted again, hopefully for the better. Please let me know what you think!